# Babel: root programmatic options

Tags: babeljs, monorepo

I seem to not grasp where to put root programmatic options for the babel.

If I have a monorepo and need to tell the different sub packages that they shall look upwards for my babel.config.js then I should put `rootMode: "upwards"` into the .babelrc of the sub packages, correct? This does not work, because of the resulting error

`Error: .rootMode is only allowed in root programmatic options`

Somehow I simply can't find any example of where to put/use root programmatic options... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Webpack, you need to put it there.

```
module: {
  [..]
  rules: [
    // Transpile ES6 Javascript into ES5 with babel loader
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: [/node_modules/, /json/],
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        rootMode: 'upward'
      },
    },
    [..]
  ],
  [..]
},
```

Otherwise I had the same issue than you, I can't put it in the package.json file using the key `babel`.

Comment: Unless of course you're not using webpack - which he may not be - I'm not using webpack and I'm encountering the same symptoms

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I specifically wanted to know if the options specified in the webpack config for the babel-loader were "programmatic" options. Your answer tells me they are.

Comment: If you're using the Babel CLI directly, pass `--root-mode upward` as [documented here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options). Took me a while to find this.

Answer (score 3):

Any API-related options are called programmatic options. Take a look at my discussion with the primary maintainer of Babel: https://github.com/babel/babel/discussions/14405.

> It's when you specify them directly to Babel (babel.transformSync(code, programmaticOptions) or to the Babel integration you are using (e.g. babel-loader, which can pass them to its internal babel.transform call). In other words, not in presets or config files. [...]
>
> by @nicolo-ribaudo - Babel core team.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error using my (probably non-standard) monorepo setup where I have top-level subdirectories for each of my packages. No top-level package. When I upgraded to Babel 7, my Jest tests were no longer transforming packages that were `yarn link`ed into the package where I was running Jest.

I added a top-level `babel.config.js` as part of [Babel's monorepo instructions](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#monorepos). I had `rootMode: "upwards"` in these three places:

- `ui-package/webpack.config.js` for transforming the app.
- `ui-package/babel-jest.js` for the tests, where it appeared like:

  ```
  module.exports = require("babel-jest").createTransformer({
    rootMode: "upward",
  })
  ```

  and was referenced from `jest.config.js` in that same dir like:

  ```
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "./babel-jest.js",
  },
  ```
- And in `/babel.config.js`, the newly added top-level babel conf file.

Removing it from the last one removed the error.